# How can i find my AccountId for my Zoho account?

Tags: zoho

Im trying to make some API calls for Zoho, like Email API.
But i am not able to make a valid request due to not knowing my Account Id.
Note that i know my User Id which i can find from my profile section in Zoho.

How can I find my Account Id?

Notes:

I tried calling this API, but getting an error.

```
http://mail.zoho.com/api/accounts
```

The error I get:

```
{"data":{"errorCode":"INVALID_TICKET","moreInfo":"Invalid ticket"},"status":{"code":400,"description":"Invalid Input"}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zoho's documentation explanation of account id:

*"Each user might have more than just one account associated with their Zoho Mail account. They might have added several POP accounts that can be accessed from the Zoho Mail interface. Each account that you associate with a Zoho account will have a separate Account ID. You'll need the account ID while passing several user and account related API requests. The account ID for each account associated with a Zoho account can be retrieved using the Organization User Details API. You will need the OrgID to fetch the User account details using this API."*

And the organization user details api mentioned is this 
https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/api/get-org-users-details.html

And here you can see you get the account id

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQqzW.png)

Comment: What about this one? This seems to return AccountId as well. https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/api/get-user-account-details.html

Comment: And unfortuantely, when i call this GET request ( http://mail.zoho.com/api/accounts) with the authorization header w/ auth token, i get this error: {"data":{"errorCode":"INVALID_TICKET","moreInfo":"Invalid ticket"},"status":{"code":400,"description":"Invalid Input"}}

Comment: Resolved my own question here. I had to correct my scope(s).